# How can I determine a file's creation date in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, file

How can I get the date of when a file was created? I am running Windows.

Comment: Under which operating system?

Comment: Cody,  windows I supose, is equal for win98/2000/vista and 7 the api have not changed

Comment: @Mandrake: It didn't say windows in the question when Cody's comment was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stat function

see [here](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/lastmod.html)

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <time.h>



struct tm* clock;               // create a time structure

struct stat attrib;         // create a file attribute structure

stat("afile.txt", &attrib);     // get the attributes of afile.txt

clock = gmtime(&(attrib.st_mtime)); // Get the last modified time and put it into the time structure
```

Comment: Does this work on Windows? Or are you assuming the OP is using UNIX?

Comment: Yea, I guess , see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Err.. I see no `stat` in that link. I do see a `_stat`.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, you should use the [GetFileAttributesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946.aspx) function for that.

Comment: I am using this approach be cause I want to know the creation date of several files, but I get the same value for all the files in the `ftCreationTime.dwLowDateTime ` and ` ftCreationTime.dwLowDateTime `, why is happen this? Thank's

Comment: @Alexander: Perhaps the files have the same value for all of them?

Comment: The files have the same date, but I was expecting some differences due to all of them have different hour

Answer (score 3):

For C, it depends on which operating system you are coding for. Files are a system dependent concept.

If you're system has it, you can go with the `stat()` (and friends) function: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html.

On Windows you may use the `GetFileTime()` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: `GetFileAttributesEx` is superior to `GetFileTime` for this particular purpose, for three reasons: 1. Using `GetFileTime` requires opening a handle to the file (and therefore the handle must be managed correctly) 2. As a result of (1), performance can suffer because the system actually has to seek to the file rather than it's MFT position 3. As a result of (1), `GetFileAttributesEx` usually requires fewer permissions than `GetFileTime`, and automatically asks for the minimal permissions require to retrieve the file's metadata rather than the file itself.

Answer (score 2):

Unix systems don't store the time of file *creation*. Unix systems *do* store the last time the file was read (if `atime` is turned on for that specific file system; sometimes it is disabled for speed), the last time the file was modified (`mtime`), and the last time the file's metadata changed (`ctime`).

See the `stat(2)` manpage for details on using it.