# is there a way to find the oldest file using just the c++

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

On Linux.

I want to build a buffer of files. A new file is saved every 30 minutes . But the total number of files allowed are 'n'.

so when 'n+1'th file is created, the oldest one has to be deleted.

I found stuff like 'dirent.h' and 'struct stat' that can help access directory, list all files and get its properties.

struct stat does not however the give time of creation, but just - last modified,last accessed, time of last status changed http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html

Please Help.

P.S: boost is not available right now.

Comment: Sure sounds like you just want the last modified stat.

Comment: Possible repeat of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842508/how-can-i-determine-a-files-creation-date-in-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux there is no such thing as file creation time saved with file in file system(s) metadata. There is something close to it, but not the same: **inode modification time** (this is the `st_ctime` member of `struct stat`). From `stat` man page:

> The field st_ctime is changed by writing or by setting inode
>   information (i.e., owner, group group,link count, mode, etc.).

**As long** as you do not modify these properties and you **do not write** (more than zero bytes) to a file(s) - the `st_ctime` is your "file creation time".

Comment: This is incorrect - the ctime will change when the mtime changes, but it *also* changes when the inode information changes.

Comment: When the mtime is changed, that's a change to the inode information, which means the ctime changes. It's not a file creation time, even if you avoid chowning/chmoding.

Comment: You are right: in case of writing (more than zero bytes) to a file the 'c_time' changes - this is the one exception from the rule.

Answer (score 2):

I needed a function that deletes the oldest file in a given directory. I used system callback functions and wrote the code in C. You can call it from C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void directoryManager(char *dir, int maxNumberOfFiles){
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *entry, *oldestFile;
struct stat statbuf;
int numberOfEntries=0;
time_t t_oldest;
double sec;

time(&t_oldest);
//printf("now:%s\n", ctime(&t_oldest));
if((dp = opendir(dir)) != NULL) {
   chdir(dir);
   while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
      lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);       
      if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
         continue;
      printf("%s\t%s", entry->d_name, ctime(&statbuf.st_mtime));
         numberOfEntries++;
      if(difftime(statbuf.st_mtime, t_oldest) < 0){
            t_oldest = statbuf.st_mtime;
         oldestFile = entry;
      }
  } 
}       

//printf("\n\n\n%s", oldestFile->d_name);
if(numberOfEntries >= maxNumberOfFiles)
   remove(oldestFile->d_name);

//printf("\noldest time:%s", ctime(&t_oldest));
closedir(dp);
}

int main(){
    directoryManager("/home/myFile", 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Onur A.'s code will run failed when directory have too many files(maybe more than 125?). Since the pointer oldestFile's value will changed on after some loops. The reason I still not found, maybe readdir() reuse that output buffer when input files more than a certain amount?
I prefer use strncpy to store oldest file's path in that code. Here's my code

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void directoryManager(char *dir, int maxNumberOfFiles) {
    DIR           *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char oldestFile[128];
    struct stat    statbuf;
    int            numberOfEntries = 0;
    time_t         t_oldest;
    double         sec;

    time(&t_oldest);
    // printf("now:%s\n", ctime(&t_oldest));
    if ((dp = opendir(dir)) != NULL) {
        chdir(dir);
        while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
            lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);
            if (strcmp(".", entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..", entry->d_name) == 0) continue;
            printf("%s\t%s", entry->d_name, ctime(&statbuf.st_mtime));
            numberOfEntries++;
            if (difftime(statbuf.st_mtime, t_oldest) < 0) {
                t_oldest   = statbuf.st_mtime;
                strncpy(oldestFile, entry->d_name, sizeof(oldestFile));
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("open %s failed\n", dir);
        return;
    }

    printf("\n\n\n%s\n", oldestFile);
    if (numberOfEntries >= maxNumberOfFiles) remove(oldestFile);
    closedir(dp);
    
}

int main() {
    directoryManager("./myFile", 5);
}
```