# Find the oldest file within a directory in C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, file, io, directory

I am working on a C project and I am trying to find the oldest file within a directory so that that once the oldest file has been found, it is then deleted. I can not find anything on how to do this in C using windows, have found ways to do it in Linux but I need a version for Windows.

Comment: [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320%28VS.85%29.aspx) should be able to help you. 
you can examine the timestamp for each file and delete the one with the oldest timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842508/how-can-i-determine-a-files-creation-date-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` combination on Windows to get the files in the directory.  You can then either use `stat` as you would in Linux, or `GetFileAttributesEx` to check the dates.

Comment: No need to make a separate call, the information returned by FindFirstFile/FindNextFile already contains the file timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you scan the directory, same as in Linux (but you could check out the Boost library also).

The data about time and date are already available in the [directory scan structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HANDLE fh;

FILETIME oldest = {-1U, -1U};

// Buffer to hold file name
oldestFile = malloc(MAX_PATH);

fd = malloc(sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == (fh = FindFirstFile(directory_name, fd)))
    // Signal error, free memory, (and return an error code?)

// OK to proceed
do
{
    if(fd->dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        continue;
    // 
    if ((fd->ftCreationTime.dwHighDateTime < oldest.dwHighDateTime)
    || (fd->ftCreationTime.dwHighDateTime == oldest.dwHighDateTime
      && fd->ftCreationTime.dwLowDateTime < oldest.dwLowDateTime))
    {
        oldest.dwHighDateTime = fd->ftCreationTime.dwHighDateTime; // ftLastAccessTime? ftLastWriteTime?
        oldest.dwLowDateTime = fd ->ft CreationTime.dwLowDateTime;
        strncpy(oldestFile, MAX_PATH, fd->cFileName);
    }
} while(FindNextFile(fh, fd));
FindClose(fh);
free(fd); fd = NULL;
```

Comment: Dunno, maybe it could be worthwhile to wrap it in an extern "C" C++ `char *find_oldest_file(char *directory)` function...

Answer (score 1):

Since windows is POSIX compliant, you should be able to read a directory and do a `stat()` on the files.

Comment: I don't know what windows you're thinking of but it isn't the windows I use.

Comment: I won't argue it's POSIX-ness, but Windows does have `stat`.

Comment: @Wug Search for `opendir(), readdir(), stat()`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463219.aspx

Comment: There's a subtle technical point here.  I believe Windows was indeed at one stage certified POSIX compliant.  However, this applies only to applications running in the Interix (Services for UNIX) subsystem, not to Win32 applications.  Note in particular that the Visual Studio runtime library does not provide stat, although it does provide _stat.  _stat, although obviously based on stat, is not guaranteed to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for clarifying. I've read about it quite some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which populates a [WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `struct` which has three time related members:

- `ftCreationTime`
- `ftLastAccessTime`
- `ftLastWriteTime`

You can compare whichever of these is more relevant and keep track of the oldest file found during iteration. Once iteration is over, delete it using [`DeleteFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The time members are of type `FILETIME` and can be compared using [`CompareFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Or use the [`GetFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain the relevant time attribute, as commented by [BeyondSora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690061/beyondsora).

Answer (score -3):

For finding the details of file in windows you'll have to refer to **File Allocation Table** which includes all the details about the files.
Check [here](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/file-allocation-table-2866.aspx) for the coding part to read FAT

Comment: And if the disk is using a different file system?

Comment: @harald But NTFS/FAT both have some File Table which stores the details about the files. FAT has a file table which contains less details and doesnt support security but NTFS has a advanced File table than FAT with more security.

Comment: the point is that you don't know what file system your program wil eventually have to read, and even if you did - you may not get access to it at that level. What if it's a mounted NFS volume? Or a remote directory mounted through sftp? Using the operating system or runtime library API's will give you the correct answer every time. Reading internal file system structures directly off the disk may be fun, but not a sensible way of solving this problem.